# How to know when RealmResults changed in RealmRecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: android, realm, listener, realmrecyclerviewadapter

Should we use in activity/fragment RealmResult query listener or we can do this using adapter. My case is to update internal counters when item was added to realm.

Comment: Why not update the internal counters where you actually do the write (in the transaction)?

Comment: At this moment I'm doing things as you said. Thank you! But i wonder if it is possible to update from adapter.

Comment: I would advise against it.

Comment: EpicPandaForce I undrestand. Thank you!